# RS232 number of bytes received

Tags: c++, c, windows, serial-port

Is there any way to find the number of bytes of data in the receive buffer of RS 232 port? In C# we can do this with the `SerialPort::BytesToRead` property.

But in my case I have to do this with C/C++. Is there any windows API to do this?

Comment: Have a look at [SerialPort Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Ports.SerialPort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [BytesToRead Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.bytestoread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, you have to use `CreateFile()`, `CloseHandle()`, `ReadFile()`, `WriteFile()` and the [serial port specific functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363194(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: The oddly named ClearCommError() returns this info.  You get pending errors (don't ignore them) and a COMSTAT whose cbInQueue member gives you the same value as SerialPort::BytesToRead.

Comment: Thank you HansPassant. ClearCommError() works well for me.